# Android Manifest for Galaxy Tablet 2

Tags: android-manifest, galaxy-tab

I have those permissions in my manifest and the app **doesn't show up** when i launch the play store on galaxy tablet. From what I read so far, it points that filtering is done based on the device profile and hardware capabilities. The device i am testing is [Samsung Galaxy Tab2](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/GT-P5113TSYXAR)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.permission.CAMERA implies both android.hardware.camera and 
android.hardware.camera.autofocus

Galaxy Tab 2 GT-P5113 doesn't have auto focus. So, that would make it filtered out. Hope it helps someone because It took me a while to find the answer.