# Android app "Incompatible" with certain devices on Google Play. Even though it works via APK

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, compatibility

We have published an Android app on Google Play. 
And on certain devices is says that it's not compatible. 
Even though the app works on those devices when installed from APK.

For example: "Samsung Galaxy Tab3 7.0 – lt02ltespr" works from APK but on google play it says that it is not supported.

Here are the details of the APK as displayed on Google Play Developer console:

```
Supported Android devices 3729 devices
    API levels 16+

    Screen layouts 4 screen layouts
    small
    normal
    large
    xlarge

    Localizations default language only

    ==== Features 5 features
    android.hardware.CAMERA
    android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
    android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
    android.hardware.touchscreen.MULTITOUCH
    android.hardware.WIFI

    ==== Required permissions 10 permissions
    android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
    android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
    android.permission.CAMERA
    android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
    android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
    android.permission.INTERNET
    android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
    android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    com.android.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT

    OpenGL ES versions 1.0+
    OpenGL textures all textures
    Native platforms armeabi, armeabi-v7a
    Uploaded on Nov 4, 2014 8:36:38 AM
```

What could be causing the problem?
Could it be a glitch in Google Play?

Comment: Also to note, that e.g. comparable Asus devices work just fine.

Comment: See if this leads you in the proper direction, I would assume this device has that feature but who knows http://stackoverflow.com/a/22156279/1628022 I noticed you use both camera and autofocus. This spec page seems to indicate the device lacks autofocus http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-3-7.0_id7834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that it was a requiring camera auto-focus in manifest and that particular Samsung tablet did not have this feature.